# Can't get windows application to run in Wine

Tags: wine

I just installed Ubuntu and would like to be able to run a Windows application using Wine. I installed Wine, and using it, installed the Windows application. The installation went fine and it created a shortcut on the desktop. However, when I try to run the app, I get an error and the application halts.

Here's the debug info. Any help in getting it work will go a long way for me to ditch Windows and embrace Ubuntu.

```
 Unhandled exception: page fault on read access to 0x00000004 in 32-bit code (0x0049fdf0).
Register dump:
 CS:0023 SS:002b DS:002b ES:002b FS:0063 GS:006b
 EIP:0049fdf0 ESP:0033c644 EBP:0033c650 EFLAGS:00210246(  R- --  I  Z- -P- )
 EAX:04e1bf58 EBX:00010578 ECX:00000000 EDX:00000000
 ESI:00ff48dc EDI:0033d648
Stack dump:
0x0033c644:  0000003c 04e1bf58 00000000 0033c69c
0x0033c654:  0049e2a1 04e1bf58 01368848 01368820
0x0033c664:  0033c680 0033c698 7e5c3546 04e1bf58
0x0033c674:  01368820 01368820 01368820 00ff48dc
0x0033c684:  fffffff4 04e1bf58 00000000 0033d05c
0x0033c694:  00d3a561 00000001 0033d068 0058aac4
000c: sel=0067 base=00000000 limit=00000000 32-bit r-x
Backtrace:
=>0 0x0049fdf0 in nesttrader (+0x9fdf0) (0x0033c650)
  1 0x0049e2a1 in nesttrader (+0x9e2a0) (0x0033c69c)
  2 0x0058aac4 in nesttrader (+0x18aac3) (0x0033d068)
  3 0x00587084 in nesttrader (+0x187083) (0x0033d074)
  4 0x0066129f in nesttrader (+0x26129e) (0x0033d080)
  5 0x78d9dc27 in mfc100 (+0x23dc26) (0x0033d1f8)
  6 0x7e5d56cd HOOKPROC_wrapper+0x4dc() in user32 (0x0033d298)
  7 0x7e5d5d3a HOOKPROC_wrapper+0xb49() in user32 (0x0033d578)
  8 0x7e622166 in user32 (+0x82165) (0x0033d718)
  9 0x7e61bd21 CreateWindowExA+0x120() in user32 (0x0033d988)
  10 0x78da3dd2 in mfc100 (+0x243dd1) (0x0033da00)
  11 0x78d9dedf in mfc100 (+0x23dede) (0x0033da74)
  12 0x78d9df92 in mfc100 (+0x23df91) (0x0033dab4)
  13 0x78da4d03 in mfc100 (+0x244d02) (0x0033dadc)
  14 0x78da4d26 in mfc100 (+0x244d25) (0x0033daf8)
  15 0x0058b3c3 in nesttrader (+0x18b3c2) (0x0033db18)
  16 0x0091b3db in nesttrader (+0x51b3da) (0x0033dbdc)
  17 0x0091bcfe in nesttrader (+0x51bcfd) (0x0033dc74)
  18 0x0091b991 in nesttrader (+0x51b990) (0x0033dc9c)
  19 0x0095cf5f in nesttrader (+0x55cf5e) (0x0033dd58)
  20 0x00954c8a in nesttrader (+0x554c89) (0x0033dec0)
  21 0x78d3f282 in mfc100 (+0x1df281) (0x0033dec8)
  22 0x7e62b09a WINPROC_wrapper+0x19() in user32 (0x0033def8)
  23 0x7e62b82b in user32 (+0x8b82a) (0x0033df48)
  24 0x7e62dfa3 in user32 (+0x8dfa2) (0x0033df98)
  25 0x7e5c0394 DefDlgProcA+0x73() in user32 (0x0033dfe8)
  26 0x7e62b09a WINPROC_wrapper+0x19() in user32 (0x0033e028)
  27 0x7e62b70a in user32 (+0x8b709) (0x0033e078)
  28 0x7e62dd74 CallWindowProcA+0x63() in user32 (0x0033e0d8)
  29 0x78d9e2b5 in mfc100 (+0x23e2b4) (0x0033e108)
  30 0x00954208 in nesttrader (+0x554207) (0x0033e124)
  31 0x78d9d7ce in mfc100 (+0x23d7cd) (0x0033e208)
  32 0x78d9f312 in mfc100 (+0x23f311) (0x0033e228)
  33 0x78d9d6ff in mfc100 (+0x23d6fe) (0x0033e2a0)
  34 0x78d9d98b in mfc100 (+0x23d98a) (0x0033e2c4)
  35 0x78c959bd in mfc100 (+0x1359bc) (0x0033e308)
  36 0x7e62b09a WINPROC_wrapper+0x19() in user32 (0x0033e338)
  37 0x7e62b70a in user32 (+0x8b709) (0x0033e388)
  38 0x7e62bbc6 in user32 (+0x8bbc5) (0x0033e858)
  39 0x7e62dcbe in user32 (+0x8dcbd) (0x0033e8a8)
  40 0x7e5f1a00 in user32 (+0x519ff) (0x0033e908)
  41 0x7e5f8c5c in user32 (+0x58c5b) (0x0033e978)
  42 0x7e5f8eed SendMessageW+0x5c() in user32 (0x0033e9d8)
  43 0x7e5c5557 in user32 (+0x25556) (0x0033ed08)
  44 0x7e5c64e7 CreateDialogIndirectParamAorW+0x36() in user32 (0x0033ed48)
  45 0x7e5c6532 CreateDialogIndirectParamA+0x31() in user32 (0x0033ed88)
  46 0x78d3f741 in mfc100 (+0x1df740) (0x0033ee00)
  47 0x78d3f5c6 in mfc100 (+0x1df5c5) (0x0033ee1c)
  48 0x78d3f572 in mfc100 (+0x1df571) (0x0033ee38)
  49 0x78d3f529 in mfc100 (+0x1df528) (0x0033ee5c)
  50 0x00402c58 in nesttrader (+0x2c57) (0x0033ee70)
  51 0x0069be4d in nesttrader (+0x29be4c) (0x0033ef90)
  52 0x00be5a79 in nesttrader (+0x7e5a78) (0x0033f0e8)
  53 0x78d9f640 in mfc100 (+0x23f63f) (0x0033f1a8)
  54 0x78d9f312 in mfc100 (+0x23f311) (0x0033f1c8)
  55 0x78d9d6ff in mfc100 (+0x23d6fe) (0x0033f240)
  56 0x78d9d98b in mfc100 (+0x23d98a) (0x0033f264)
  57 0x78c959bd in mfc100 (+0x1359bc) (0x0033f2a8)
  58 0x7e62b09a WINPROC_wrapper+0x19() in user32 (0x0033f2d8)
  59 0x7e62b70a in user32 (+0x8b709) (0x0033f328)
  60 0x7e62dc49 in user32 (+0x8dc48) (0x0033f378)
  61 0x7e5f1a00 in user32 (+0x519ff) (0x0033f3d8)
  62 0x7e5f8c5c in user32 (+0x58c5b) (0x0033f448)
  63 0x7e5fb0d4 SendMessageA+0x63() in user32 (0x0033f4a8)
  64 0x7e622830 in user32 (+0x8282f) (0x0033f648)
  65 0x7e61bd21 CreateWindowExA+0x120() in user32 (0x0033f8b8)
  66 0x78da3dd2 in mfc100 (+0x243dd1) (0x0033f930)
  67 0x78d9dedf in mfc100 (+0x23dede) (0x0033f9a4)
  68 0x78dab4a4 in mfc100 (+0x24b4a3) (0x0033f9e8)
  69 0x78dab745 in mfc100 (+0x24b744) (0x0033fa34)
  70 0x78db212e in mfc100 (+0x25212d) (0x0033fa50)
  71 0x00bff91b in nesttrader (+0x7ff91a) (0x0033fda8)
  72 0x78db1cc3 in mfc100 (+0x251cc2) (0x0033fdbc)
  73 0x00d25f23 in nesttrader (+0x925f22) (0x0033fe50)
  74 0x7b85a75c call_process_entry+0xb() in kernel32 (0x0033fe68)
  75 0x7b85b75a ExitProcess+0xff9() in kernel32 (0x0033fe98)
  76 0x7bc76830 call_thread_func_wrapper+0xb() in ntdll (0x0033feb8)
  77 0x7bc7965f call_thread_func+0xce() in ntdll (0x0033ffa8)
  78 0x7bc7680e RtlRaiseException+0x21() in ntdll (0x0033ffc8)
  79 0x7bc4cd97 call_dll_entry_point+0x766() in ntdll (0x0033ffe8)
  80 0xf755c15d wine_call_on_stack+0x1c() in libwine.so.1 (0x00000000)
  81 0xf755c2d0 wine_switch_to_stack+0x1f() in libwine.so.1 (0xff99baf8)
  82 0x7bc5221a LdrInitializeThunk+0x339() in ntdll (0xff99bb58)
  83 0x7b861373 __wine_kernel_init+0x872() in kernel32 (0xff99ccb8)
  84 0x7bc52793 __wine_process_init+0x162() in ntdll (0xff99cd28)
  85 0xf7559dc7 wine_init+0x306() in libwine.so.1 (0xff99cd88)
  86 0x7bf00d52 main+0x81() in <wine-loader> (0xff99d1d8)
  87 0xf7387a83 __libc_start_main+0xf2() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
0x0049fdf0: movl    0x4(%ecx),%edx
Modules:
Module  Address         Debug info  Name (129 modules)
PE    340000-  37c000   Deferred        glut32
PE    380000-  3bd000   Deferred        ssleay32
PE    3c0000-  3cc000   Deferred        excel
PE    3d0000-  3dd000   Deferred        nesttools
PE    3e0000-  3f2000   Deferred        zlib1
PE    400000- 121b000   Export          nesttrader
PE   1220000- 133d000   Deferred        libeay32
PE   1450000- 1491000   Deferred        reportgenerator
PE  10000000-10016000   Deferred        zlibwapi
PE  78050000-780b9000   Deferred        msvcp100
PE  78aa0000-78b5f000   Deferred        msvcr100
PE  78b60000-78f98000   Export          mfc100
ELF 7ac00000-7ac5d000   Deferred        riched20<elf>
  \-PE  7ac10000-7ac5d000   \               riched20
ELF 7b800000-7ba54000   Dwarf           kernel32<elf>
  \-PE  7b810000-7ba54000   \               kernel32
ELF 7bc00000-7bcda000   Dwarf           ntdll<elf>
  \-PE  7bc10000-7bcda000   \               ntdll
ELF 7bf00000-7bf04000   Dwarf           <wine-loader>
ELF 7d271000-7d2b1000   Deferred        usp10<elf>
  \-PE  7d280000-7d2b1000   \               usp10
ELF 7d2b1000-7d2c8000   Deferred        libresolv.so.2
ELF 7d2c8000-7d2cf000   Deferred        libnss_dns.so.2
ELF 7d2e8000-7d400000   Deferred        actxprxy<elf>
  \-PE  7d300000-7d400000   \               actxprxy
ELF 7d5bc000-7d5d1000   Deferred        vdmdbg<elf>
  \-PE  7d5c0000-7d5d1000   \               vdmdbg
ELF 7d5d1000-7d5f8000   Deferred        mpr<elf>
  \-PE  7d5e0000-7d5f8000   \               mpr
ELF 7d678000-7d68c000   Deferred        riched32<elf>
  \-PE  7d680000-7d68c000   \               riched32
ELF 7d68c000-7d702000   Deferred        wininet<elf>
  \-PE  7d6a0000-7d702000   \               wininet
ELF 7d702000-7d726000   Deferred        imm32<elf>
  \-PE  7d710000-7d726000   \               imm32
ELF 7d78f000-7d7c5000   Deferred        uxtheme<elf>
  \-PE  7d7a0000-7d7c5000   \               uxtheme
ELF 7d7c5000-7d7d0000   Deferred        libxcursor.so.1
ELF 7d7d0000-7d7e2000   Deferred        libxi.so.6
ELF 7d7e2000-7d7e6000   Deferred        libxcomposite.so.1
ELF 7d7e6000-7d7f1000   Deferred        libxrandr.so.2
ELF 7d7f1000-7d7fc000   Deferred        libxrender.so.1
ELF 7d7fc000-7d800000   Deferred        libxinerama.so.1
ELF 7d801000-7d817000   Deferred        dwmapi<elf>
  \-PE  7d810000-7d817000   \               dwmapi
ELF 7d819000-7d8a6000   Deferred        winex11<elf>
  \-PE  7d820000-7d8a6000   \               winex11
ELF 7d8f2000-7d92e000   Deferred        libfontconfig.so.1
ELF 7d92e000-7d95a000   Deferred        libpng12.so.0
ELF 7d95a000-7d974000   Deferred        libz.so.1
ELF 7d974000-7da24000   Deferred        libfreetype.so.6
ELF 7da3d000-7da51000   Deferred        psapi<elf>
  \-PE  7da40000-7da51000   \               psapi
ELF 7da51000-7dc7a000   Deferred        shell32<elf>
  \-PE  7da60000-7dc7a000   \               shell32
ELF 7dc7a000-7dd05000   Deferred        gdiplus<elf>
  \-PE  7dc90000-7dd05000   \               gdiplus
ELF 7dd05000-7dd20000   Deferred        wsock32<elf>
  \-PE  7dd10000-7dd20000   \               wsock32
ELF 7dd20000-7dd45000   Deferred        iphlpapi<elf>
  \-PE  7dd30000-7dd45000   \               iphlpapi
ELF 7dd45000-7de6f000   Deferred        oleaut32<elf>
  \-PE  7dd60000-7de6f000   \               oleaut32
ELF 7de6f000-7de83000   Deferred        msimg32<elf>
  \-PE  7de70000-7de83000   \               msimg32
ELF 7de83000-7df7b000   Deferred        comctl32<elf>
  \-PE  7de90000-7df7b000   \               comctl32
ELF 7df7b000-7dff1000   Deferred        shlwapi<elf>
  \-PE  7df90000-7dff1000   \               shlwapi
ELF 7dff1000-7e01e000   Deferred        msvcr90<elf>
  \-PE  7e000000-7e01e000   \               msvcr90
ELF 7e01e000-7e053000   Deferred        ws2_32<elf>
  \-PE  7e030000-7e053000   \               ws2_32
ELF 7e053000-7e170000   Deferred        opengl32<elf>
  \-PE  7e070000-7e170000   \               opengl32
ELF 7e170000-7e19b000   Deferred        msacm32<elf>
  \-PE  7e180000-7e19b000   \               msacm32
ELF 7e19b000-7e217000   Deferred        rpcrt4<elf>
  \-PE  7e1b0000-7e217000   \               rpcrt4
ELF 7e217000-7e344000   Deferred        ole32<elf>
  \-PE  7e230000-7e344000   \               ole32
ELF 7e344000-7e3fc000   Deferred        winmm<elf>
  \-PE  7e350000-7e3fc000   \               winmm
ELF 7e3fc000-7e46b000   Deferred        advapi32<elf>
  \-PE  7e410000-7e46b000   \               advapi32
ELF 7e46b000-7e584000   Deferred        gdi32<elf>
  \-PE  7e480000-7e584000   \               gdi32
ELF 7e584000-7e6d1000   Dwarf           user32<elf>
  \-PE  7e5a0000-7e6d1000   \               user32
ELF 7e6d1000-7e6d8000   Deferred        libxdmcp.so.6
ELF 7e6d8000-7e6dc000   Deferred        libxau.so.6
ELF 7e6dc000-7e6ea000   Deferred        libdrm.so.2
ELF 7e6ea000-7e6f0000   Deferred        libxxf86vm.so.1
ELF 7e6f0000-7e6f3000   Deferred        libxshmfence.so.1
ELF 7e6f3000-7e715000   Deferred        libxcb.so.1
ELF 7e715000-7e71c000   Deferred        libxcb-sync.so.1
ELF 7e71c000-7e720000   Deferred        libxcb-present.so.0
ELF 7e720000-7e724000   Deferred        libxcb-dri3.so.0
ELF 7e724000-7e72a000   Deferred        libxcb-dri2.so.0
ELF 7e72a000-7e742000   Deferred        libxcb-glx.so.0
ELF 7e742000-7e88d000   Deferred        libx11.so.6
ELF 7e88d000-7e890000   Deferred        libx11-xcb.so.1
ELF 7e890000-7e8a3000   Deferred        libxext.so.6
ELF 7e8a3000-7e8bc000   Deferred        libglapi.so.0
ELF 7e8bc000-7e8e5000   Deferred        libexpat.so.1
ELF 7e8e5000-7e903000   Deferred        libgcc_s.so.1
ELF 7e9f8000-7eaa2000   Deferred        libgl.so.1
ELF 7eaa2000-7eb15000   Deferred        libglu.so.1
ELF 7eb15000-7eb2e000   Deferred        version<elf>
  \-PE  7eb20000-7eb2e000   \               version
ELF 7eb2e000-7ebdb000   Deferred        msvcrt<elf>
  \-PE  7eb40000-7ebdb000   \               msvcrt
ELF 7ebdb000-7ebf6000   Deferred        crtdll<elf>
  \-PE  7ebe0000-7ebf6000   \               crtdll
ELF 7ebf6000-7ec03000   Deferred        libnss_files.so.2
ELF 7ec03000-7ec0f000   Deferred        libnss_nis.so.2
ELF 7ec0f000-7ec28000   Deferred        libnsl.so.1
ELF 7ec28000-7ec31000   Deferred        libnss_compat.so.2
ELF 7efa1000-7efe7000   Deferred        libm.so.6
ELF 7efe8000-7f000000   Deferred        glu32<elf>
  \-PE  7eff0000-7f000000   \               glu32
ELF f7361000-f7368000   Deferred        libxfixes.so.3
ELF f7369000-f736e000   Deferred        libdl.so.2
ELF f736e000-f751c000   Dwarf           libc.so.6
ELF f751d000-f753a000   Deferred        libpthread.so.0
ELF f753c000-f7540000   Deferred        libxdamage.so.1
ELF f7553000-f7709000   Dwarf           libwine.so.1
ELF f770b000-f772d000   Deferred        ld-linux.so.2
ELF f772d000-f772e000   Deferred        [vdso].so
Threads:
process  tid      prio (all id:s are in hex)
0000000e services.exe
    0000001e    0
    0000001d    0
    00000018    0
    00000016    0
    00000014    0
    00000010    0
    0000000f    0
00000012 winedevice.exe
    0000001c    0
    00000019    0
    00000017    0
    00000013    0
0000001a plugplay.exe
    00000020    0
    0000001f    0
    0000001b    0
00000021 explorer.exe
    00000023    0
    00000022    0
00000024 (D) C:\Program Files\Omnesys\NEST3\NestTrader.exe
    0000002f    0
    0000002e    0
    0000002d    0
    0000002c    0
    0000002b    0
    0000002a    0
    00000029    0
    00000028    0
    00000027    0
    00000026    0
    00000025    0 <==
System information:
    Wine build: wine-1.6.2
    Platform: i386 (WOW64)
    Host system: Linux
    Host version: 3.16.0-23-generic
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be [an issue common to NEST Trader](https://bugs.winehq.org/show_bug.cgi?id=31491). It seems rather niche and the bug hasn't been that active  because there aren't enough Wine developers who use it. That's just the way things can be in open source some times.

You have a few options:

- Ask Omnesys to improve their software so that it works on Wine (or even release a native client)
- Find and pay somebody to keep hacking on Wine until it works. [Codeweavers](https://www.codeweavers.com/) (the main company behind Wine) do have commercial support but I don't think it would be practical to have them fix this just for you. Capable independent developers exist but I don't know how you'd advertise the job.
- Find an alternative application.
- Install Windows in a VM running on Ubuntu and install and use Nest in that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I thought may be installing some library or something could help resolve the problem.
Anyway, my next question is, if I install Windows in a VM, will the app be fast enough. It's a stock trading app that runs online, so time and response is of essence here.

Comment: I use a VM for a few graphics editing applications and it's fast enough for me... I can't tell you how it'll be *for you*. Try it.